# Curtain menu is not recognizing my javascript source code

Tags: javascript, html

I am using w3school as my learning portal, but now I am facing problem. When I run code with all source code in html file, it works fine. But when I put the javascript source code into external js. file, it nothing happens.

The functional one is here : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agentkocicka/es6d05rh/)

The javascript code is:

```
    function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

This code I replace with `<script src="/js/w3school_index.js"></script>` because the file is located in directory named "js"

Should I call the source code when I call the method in the HTML file? Or it is enought to call it like I have? Or should I add some code into javascript file?

Comment: You must understand that javascript must be loaded after the dom is initialized, so make sure that it is loaded after, also do you have an error ? Maybe your script isn't found

Comment: Read up on [JavaScript initalization](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/init.php). Maybe also read about `defer`. Also, you can remove the first slash from your `src`.